# Using the Concatenating of an apostrophe and the reference of a cell inside the INDIRECT function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

i have one particular question about this case of concatenation(**shown on the picture 1**, if you can't see it, the content that i want to show with it is: **=VLOOKUP(C3;INDIRECT(" ' "&B3&" '!B3:C7");2;FALSE)**). I was practicing the VLOOKUP function,using the indirect function inside it, and at some point, along with the indirect function arguments, it was used as a reference one cell that doesn't belong to the same sheet that the function VLOOKUP was being used. So to reference this cell, to make a dynamic reference and in order to concatenate the apostrophe of the name of the other sheet with the dynamic reference cell, i saw a video of a guy using the syntax that i'll attach as an image along with this question.

After this long text, my question is how this syntax works? I learned that to concatenate something on excel with the **&**, i just need to use the **&** before the stuff that i want to concatenate. But in the **case shown on the attachment 1**, it's used some " then a ' and then ", resulting in this shape " ' ";  so came the & and after the reference of the cell, it was used the & " and the '. I don't know if i was clear enough on my question. But can someone explain to me this thing? I cannot see the need of this kind of use of the &, neither the need of using this " repeteadly on the indirect function. The name of the sheed that i intend to emulate with the indirect function, and the reason of the need of the apostrophe is shown on the **picture 2**(if is not easy to see on the pic, it is **='Branch 1'!B3**).

enter image description here
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try (there will be more knowledgeable heads than mine after my scalp in a moment :-)

"'" & B3 & "'" concatenates two strings (text) with a variant (number, text or date). Presuming that B3 contains the word "breakfast" (text), the total formula would evaluate to "'" & "breakfast" & "'" and you would be quite right to argue that the three could be merged as "'breakfast'" but that hypothetical case doesn't logically arise because there is a difference in the handling each component needs. The variant must first be converted to string which the two apostrophes don't require.

Presuming that B3 contains the number 144 (or a formula evaluating to that number) the result will be "'144'". As you can see, the number in B3 was converted to text. A different conversion, also to text, would happen if B3 were to contain a date.

So, the answer to your question would be that "'" designates the characters between quotation marks as text to be used as is while characters not surrounded by quotation marks are for evaluation and appropriate conversion. This becomes very clear in the example "'B3'" which Excel would return as exactly what it was given, WYSIWYG as they used to say, and we would never know what's in B3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there are somethings that i still didnt get it, 
The variant must first be converted to string which the two apostrophes don't require.- Is it because the variant breakfast is already a text?
And i still don't see how it was made to concatenate the ', and the "breakfast", you said that first of all the variant will need to be convert to string, but why the & is inside the conversion to string? This syntax still confuses me!  I am used to see this kind of conversion and concat by this way: ' & "breakfast" &', i don't understand why it's like ''' & "breakfast" & '''

Comment: In VBA an apostrophe is a character like A, B or C, and single characters are to VBA like short words. "breakfast" is a word, "A" is a word and "'" is a word. All words are surrounded by by quotation marks. (""" therefore creates a word of one quotation mark.) The ampersand is a concatenation mark, comparable to the plus sign in 4 + 4. It tells VBA to combine the two strings into one: "O" & "K" = "OK". A reference, like B3 isn't a string because it needs to be evaluated to a string first (if possible). Therefore it must be presented without surrounding quotation marks in the concatenation.

Comment: In fact, if this makes the role of the ampersand clearer, it can often be replaced with the plus sign. "O" + "K" will work. "'" + B3 + "'" is also likely to work. The latter example concatenates 3 strings, one of which is supplied as a reference which needs conversion. You will get the hang of it once you recognize the parts for what they are. Each block of "'" is a ready text string, B3 is a variant waiting to be converted to text. The two ampersands are instructions to concatenate. There is no conversion string. There is concatenation syntax.

Comment: Now i guess i get it, so  this  "'" + B3 + "'" will take the reference and convert into a string due to the concatenation with the quotation mark, and the remaining quotation marks that are on the left of the apostrophe and in the end of the argument of the function will convert the whole set as a string, including the apostrophe, what will make possible the concatenation between the apostrophe and the B3, once turned into a string?
And the syntax, "'" + B3 + "'", would be equivalent to +"B3"+? I typed on this second way and didn't work out as a valid argument. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Looks promising but `would be equivalent to +"B3"+` - no. Converted to a numeric expression your `+ "B3" +` would look like ` + "Four" + `. You are missing a number before the first plus and one after the last plus and "Four" isn't a number the formula can calculate. `2 + 4 + 3` is the sense you're after. It seems you expect the apo to be a delimiter, and you are right. In `INDIRECT(" ' " & B3 & " '!B3:C7"` the apos embrace the sheet name ("'My Sheet'!B3:C7") but that name must be passed to the function as a string including the embracing apos. So, they aren't delimiters yet at that point.

Comment: I understand the latter part of your answer, but sorry to ask you again, i'm a novice in this subject. So basically, the difference of  + "B3" + and '" + B3 + "' would be that in the first case it'll return the string B3 and concatenate and in the second case, it will search for the value on B3 and after this, will concatenate with the apo ?

Comment: Please understand that in VBA double quotation marks enclose strings. Whatever is between quotation marks is a string. Whatever isn't isn't. When VBA interfaces with other languages the means of communication is usually a string. Therefore VBA writes it between quotation marks. Those strings can include single quotation marks which the other program sometimes interprets in some ways not shared by VBA.

Comment: The basic rule that strings are enclosed in quotation marks leaves us with 2 problems. One is how to concatenate strings and non-strings. The other is how to include a quotation mark within a string. "String" & "String" concatenates two strings. "String" & 14 & "String" concatenates text, number and text. "string" & B3 & "string" concatenates text with a reference and text.. In each case the strings are enclosed in quotation marks and the non-strings aren't.

Comment: Now i get it!  I was not able to figure out these differences until now, thank you!